# 1 Domain - 2 Stores - both of them in English and German - How to get Language Tag in URL?

Tags: magento2, multistore, url, store-view, language

**Stores:**

- automobile
- truck

**Languages:**

- German
- English

**StoreViews Codes:**

- automobile German: auto
- automobile English: car
- truck German: laster
- truck English: truck

**Desired urls:**

- automobile German: example.com/de/auto
- automobile English: example.com/en/car
- truck German: example.com/de/laster
- truck English: example.com/en/truck

**Problem**
I can get the store view code in the URL but I am not able to get the language tag in the URL. How can I build the aforementioned URLs in Magento 2?

**Edit:**
From my point of view, this is not a duplicate since I don't want to have multiple websites. I want one website and multiple stores with store codes in the URL AND the language tag in the URL.

Comment: use full store url or create rewrite with language path, so your shop base url `example.com/de/`

Comment: What exactly do you mean? If I change the base url to example.com/de/ in the store view config I get a 404 ... I already tried this...

Comment: you have to use both store code in server config and rewrite. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html